Batch Preprocessing of Motion Capture Files in .npy Format
I am working on a project where I need to preprocess multiple motion capture files stored in .npy format. I am able to load and preprocess individual files, but I am facing difficulties when trying to process multiple files in a directory. The goal is to iterate through all the .npy files, apply pre
import os
import numpy as np

motion_dir = "path/to/motion_files"
motion_files = [f for f in os.listdir(motion_dir) if f.endswith('.npy')]

processed_data = []

for file_path in motion_files:
    try:
        # Load the .npy file
        data = np.load(os.path.join(motion_dir, file_path))
        
        # Example of preprocessing: Normalization
        data = (data - np.mean(data)) / np.std(data)
        processed_data.append(data)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {file_path}: {e}")

The issue I am facing is that I can load multiple .npy files correctly, but I cannot preprocess them all together. When I load the files, the data appears to be stored as a single vector or list, which makes it difficult to apply the preprocessing (such as normalization) correctly.
Is there a more efficient way to handle loading and processing multiple .npy files in Python?
Are there best practices for handling .npy file formats in one workflow?
How can I preprocess these multiple .npy files efficiently while preserving the structure of the data?

"When I load the files, the data appears to be stored as a single vector or list, which makes it difficult to apply the preprocessing (such as normalization) correctly." What does that mean? Are you talking about the data variable? I assume it's a numpy array, but what did you expect it to be? What is the shape of the array?

It's unclear what sort of 'batch' processing you have in mind.  load fetches one array from one file.  What you do with that array is up to you.  Maybe you want to collect a bunch of the arrays in a list first, concatenate if shapes allow and work with the larger multidimensional array.  You don't provide enough info.
